# Why do I need to set a display type for displaying my image on a mobile viewport?

Tags: html, css

I have an image contained within a div. When I used the code below for displaying the image on my desktop, it displayed fine. But when I used the same code for displaying it on a mobile device, the image would not display, unless I added display:block; to both the image and the container div. All the videos and articles I have read for displaying images do not tell me I need to use display:block; so I don't understand why I need to use it for displaying on a mobile. Why is it that I don't need to use display:block for a desktop but I do for a mobile phone?

CSS for desktop view:

```
.index-image{
width: 100%;
}
.index-image > img{
width:100%;
}
```

HTML for desktop view:

```
<div class="index-image">
<img src="images/coding.jpg"/>  
</div>
```

CSS for mobile view:

```
.index-image-mobile {
display:block;
width:100%;
}

.index-image-mobile > img{
display:block;
width:100%;
}

.index-image{
display:none;
}
```

HTML for mobile view:

```
<div class="index-image-mobile">
<img src="images/coding-mobile.jpg"/>  
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't. It could be possible that there is a css issue elsewhere.